# Bluetooth audio device not under playback devices after pairing

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, headphones

I have the Sennheiser PXC 360 BT headphones and a new laptop with Windows 8.

On my previous laptop I simply paired the headphones with Windows and it was always displayed under my audio playback devices, whether it was connected or not. To connect it you simply right click and hit connect. This worked perfectly (and is actually the only new feature I really like in Windows 8).

On my new laptop I went through the same process, paired the headphones with Windows and it connected and played right away without any issues. The headset was listed under playback devices and immediatly set as default playback device.

The problem started after a reboot. **The headphones are gone from the list of playback devices.**

- I checked if all devices are being displayed, they are (show disabled and disconnected devices are ticked).
- I checked if the headphones are still paired, and yes they are (under the metro PC settings -> PC and Devices -> Bluetooth), but I can't do anything but remove it there.
- I tried removing the headphones at the settings mentioned above and re-pairing it. This made it work but only until the next reboot when they dissapeared again...

I tried doing some googling but keep finding unrelated bluetooth problems with specific devices which I doubt this is (since it worked on the other laptop)

The only difference I can image is the wireless/bluetooth device in my laptop. It's a Bigfoot Killer Wireless-N 1202. If I check my device manager under bluetooth I see it includes a Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 + HS.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Broadcom Bluetooth 4.0 Driver for Windows 8.1 ] LINK=>> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkTYP.png) ! 
At least works fine on my HP-EliteBook-8570p with stereo "BlueDio 99B" headset. After switching the headset ON the Windows connect the device automatically, and switch Audio-Stream into new-attached device. Optimal!
 PS - Unfortunately it is still the Problem with Windows 8.1 + Skype( MIC-Problem) :( Windows 8 is the first OS, than not support Skype at all! ;)

[image: Connected BT Headset]
[image: AudioIN]
[image: AudioOUT]

Comment: This is unlikely to work *unless* the OP has the same brand of bluetooth hardware that you have: Broadcom.